# Pubnub 3.7.2 disable logging Android SDK

Tags: android, pubnub

I have searched the API Docs for this, but haven't been able to figure out how to disable verbose logging. This version spams the logs too much, it's very irritating.

Anyone knows how to disable logging in this version? Or point me to the API reference?

Comment: Did you figure out the way to disable it ?

Comment: Nope. Still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

General information on PubNub Java logging is available at https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk-troubleshooting-guide

If this information still leaves you with questions, please shoot an email to support@pubnub.com and we'll take it from there.

Comment: The docs don't mention an easy way to stop the logs. And I don't think I will take the long approach of disabling the logs. For now, I guess, I can live with it, although it's very irritating.

Comment: When you say "stop the logs", do you mean, while running the debug build, to turn off logging?

Comment: I have sent a support email for this.

Comment: Broken link, @Geremy, please fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You should be seeing debug logs only if you are using a debug jar. Please verify if the jar you are using is debug one or normal.

Comment: I am using the normal jar.

Comment: I am also using normal jar and seeing the behaviour